# Trying to present tableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

```
  tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width/2, height: view.frame.height/2))
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 50.0).isActive = true
```

I have been trying to figure out how to present this UITableView on my main view but it does not seem to work. Please let me know if you know how to do it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your frame will not be used once you set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoContraints = false`.  Add `NSLayoutConstraint`s for table width and height.  Also, you need to implement some tableView delegate and datasource methods.

Comment: The problem was with the frame. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When using auto layout, we usually implement one of these constraint:

1. Pin 4 edge to superview
2. Set width, height to a fixed number or percent of superview, then we determine origin point by set x, y or center it horizontally and vertically.

So I recommend you i**mplement two more constraints** to TableView's width and TableView's height instead of set it's frame.

Finally, do not forget it it to your root view hierarchy like: self.view.addSubview(tableView)